# What is the privilege my user requires to be able to grant CONNECT, RESOURCE and CREATE SESSION to other users in Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle-11g, permissions

What is the privilege my user requires to be able to grant the following privileges

CONNECT, RESOURCE and CREATE SESSION

to OTHER users in Oracle 11g?

Comment: `connect` and `create session` is the same thing. There is no need to grant both.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: no, that is wrong, they are not the same thing. CONNECT is a role that has granted the system privilege CREATE SESSION.

Answer (score 3):

If a system privilege is granted with ADMIN OPTION to a user, this user can grant this system privileges to other users, e.g. after

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO SCOTT WITH ADMIN OPTION
```

Scott is able to grant CREATE TABLE to other users. He is also able to grant CREATE TABLE to other users WITH GRANT OPTION. WITH GRANT OPTION works for roles too.

An object privileges (like a select on a table) must be granted WITH GRANT OPTION to a user to grant it to another user.

```
GRANT SELECT ON HR.EMPLOYEES TO SCOTT WITH GRANT OPTION
```

This can be found in the [SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9013.htm#SQLRF01603)